# C# How to replace \" with "

Tags: c#

I want to replace all \" in a string with ", but don't know how.
I'v tried:

```
result=result.Replace("\\\"","\"");
```

It doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: That should work - where are you seeing the "wrong" values?

Comment: Where are you looking at the result string? If it's in the debugger, it'll put a \ before every ", but the string will appear "normally" everywhere else.

Comment: It really will work, but I suspect you're looking at the string in the debugger, and getting thrown off by that.

Comment: If it's really going wrong, and you aren't just looking at results in the debugger as mentioned, try searching here using these terms: `[c#] unescape string`. You will get many results showing likely solutions to your problem.

Comment: If the string does not really contain the sequence ``\`` `"` but only contains `"` with no backslash, of course your `Replace` will replace zero occurences. You might _think_ the string is different than it really is, because of the debugger display format.

Comment: are you trying to replace the **\"** for **",** ? It's a little hard to understand what you really want.

Comment: could you post an extract of the string you have and the string you want? as it stand your code seems right to me

Comment: Give us an example string.  Show us what your code returns and then what you want it to return.

Answer (score 3):

check the below code, this works perfectly.

```
result=result.Replace(@"\"+"\"","\"");
```

**This is how I tried:**

```
string given = "google\\\"";
System.Console.WriteLine(given);
string result = given.Replace(@"\"+"\"","\"");
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output:**

> google\"
>
> google"

Comment: Though `@"\\" + "\""` is the exact same thing as `"\\\""`.  Hopefully howexg9 will comment or update his question as to WHAT is going wrong.

Comment: @Tory Yup, you're right.  While checking first I tried that first in online code editor, it showed me error.  But now this is working.  Thanks for that :).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
result = result.Replace(@"\" + '"', "\"");
```

Comment: This will be no different than the code the OP is using, it only looks different.

Comment: Can you post the initial value of the string result?

Answer (score -4):

Uh yeah, Jonesy... I was just typing out close to the exact same thing:

```
string result = @"\\Hi\\";
result.Replace(@"\",String.Empty);

//result is now: "Hi"
```

re-reading the question, I think theres just a little confusion on escaping chars in strings, and as earlier comment said, maybe looking at results in immediate window?. Using literal operator makes its easier to read, and use.

Jonesy and Esoteric are reading more into the question than is there. If there are Escape sequences, to be dealt with that is another question. Which is easy to do with regex...

Comment: What? I was replying to answers that he's not looking for a String.Empty

Comment: The question is *not* about how to remove all backslashes from a string. It asks, quite specifically, how to replace `\"` with `"` in a given string. I.e., removing those backslashes which immediately precede a double quote character. Removing all backslashes will do that but will also have undesirable side effects, such as unescaping every other escaped character in the string, or removing backslashes which are part of the data.